# Adjusting the word-spacing and text-align of <img>s

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a series of `<img>`—essentially just a bunch of small icons. The text-align of this containing div changes at different points. Sometimes it is right-aligned, sometimes left, and sometimes justified.

**Problem 1: I want there to be spacing between each of the images in this div.**

This is very easy to accomplish by giving them a margin. However, say they are currently aligned right. I would need to put the margin on the left of each, which is all well and good.

[image]

But then when they become left aligned or justified, the margin will be pushing the left most one off from the left side slightly.

[image]

I had hoped I would be able to use something like word-spacing on the containing div, in order to control how much space is between each image. But apparently, you cannot control them in the way you control text.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

**Problem 2: The images will not justify, because they only take up 1 line.**

I have read that the solution to this is to add a pseudo-element to the container, but this does not seem to work properly. I may be missing something.

I even tried adding a `<br>` and a `&nbsp;` to the end of the images, but this did not have the effect of creating a new line therefore justifying the first line like I wanted it to.

Here is how the code is set up:

```
<div id="projectPagePieces" style="width: 100%; text-align: justify;">
    <img title="Identity" src="imgs/icons/Identity.png">
    <img title="Festival Program" src="imgs/icons/Book.png">
    <img title="Poster" src="imgs/icons/Poster.png">
    <img title="Festival Trailer" src="imgs/icons/Video.png">
    <img title="Business Cards" src="imgs/icons/BusinessCard.png">
    <br> &nbsp;
</div>
```

---

```
#projectPagePieces {
    width:30%;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:text-top;
    text-align:right;
}

#projectPagePieces:after{ /*adds an extra line so first line will justify*/
    content:"";
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100%; 
}

#projectPagePieces img {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    height:20px;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: This is where you should be using the margins, not word spacing... If you can provide a image or how you would like this to show then it would be easier to know what you mean..

Comment: @Mayhem aright, added images showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, I was able to get your code to work in both cases.

I could not quite work out why you were running into issues, but at least
you now have a working example.

```css
.projectPagePieces {
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    word-spacing: 25px;
    line-height: 0;
}
.projectPagePieces img {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
.projectPagePieces.stretch {
text-align: justify;
}
.projectPagePieces.stretch:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<h2>Ex 1</h2>
<div class="projectPagePieces">
    <img title="Identity" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img title="Festival Program" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img title="Poster" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img title="Festival Trailer"  src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img title="Business Cards" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
<h2>Ex 2</h2>
<div class="projectPagePieces stretch">
    <img title="Identity" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img title="Festival Program" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img title="Poster" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img title="Festival Trailer"  src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img title="Business Cards" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct, this is working for me as well. Tried it in a fiddle and played around with it there, it still works there too. For the life of me I can't figure out what the problem could possibly be - when inspecting the elements their styles appear exactly as in your code and the fiddle but do not work. Is there anything that could cause this? Should I just link to the site so you can test it?